# BizTalk Receive port produces extra, empty files

Tags: xml, biztalk

I am running onto a repeated issue with BizTalk. I have an AS2 receive location who's only job is to accept an XML file so BizTalk Send port can pick it up and pass it to a stored procedure that reads it into our Database.  The send port has a single filter: `BTS.ReceivePortName == "ReceivePortName"`, so the only files that should be passed to it are files from that single receive port.

However, for every file our client sends up, the file is first processed without error, followed immediately by a second, empty file with no content also being passed to the receive port.  Obviously, this throws a database error when the stored procedure runs, which causes the send port to suspend.

So for every file we get, I also get a "Phantom" file that must be coming from the receive port, because the send port can ONLY receive from that port. However, that port should only be receiving from the client, who insists they are not sending a second file.  Thus I get stuck in a mental loop of trying to track where this is coming from.

Any ideas on how I can track this?  Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal, the empty message is created by BizTalk to - I assume - trigger the MDN internally.

Use an extra filter: `IsAS2PayloadMessage = True`

See also MSDN: [AS2 Context properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226483.aspx)

Comment: Thank you!  It worked exactly as you said. I am still new to BizTalk and was not aware of that function.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the normal and expected behavior of BizTalk and AS2 processing.

There are two possibilities:

1. The second message is the MDN you are generating which is supposed to be returned to the caller ASYNC *because they are requesting it*.
2. The caller is returning MDNs to you at the same time for messages sent to them.

Most likely, it's #1.  [Walkthrough (AS2): Receiving EDI over AS2 with an Asynchronous MDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727975.aspx) describes how to handle async MDNs.

**Note, you can't just ignore them.**  The caller is requesting them and likely requires the MDN to complete their process.